# SQL - How to calculate three different percentages for each Team

Tags: sql, database

Here is my sample data

```
CREATE TABLE Grades
([Team] varchar(10),[Grade] Integer, [Target] Integer);

INSERT INTo Grades VALUES ('A',26,25);
INSERT INTo Grades VALUES ('A',13,35);
INSERT INTo Grades VALUES ('A',13,15);
INSERT INTO Grades VALUES ('B',10,20);
INSERT INTo Grades VALUES ('B',13,11);
INSERT INTO Grades VALUES ('C',20,30);
```

Here is my failed attempts

```
   Select Team, 
    (count(case when Grade >= Target then Target else Grade end) * 100 /  

    (SELECT count(Target) FROM Grades)) As Target
    From Grades
    GROUP BY Team
```

Problem - I can do it as a percentage as a whole, but I am struggling how to differentiate these percentages into their own teams.

I thought GROUP BY could split them apart, but the SQL query still sums the whole column and this is where my understanding of SQL becomes limited in scope of what to do.

**Explanation**

Each record insertted will have a Grade and Target, the grade can exceed the target and if it does, it uses the target value to prevent the percentage exceeding over 100 when it is all aggregated.

For example

Team B, has 10 for grade and it is less than target 20. In this case, we use 10 and add this to the total. BUT next, we have another row that belongs to Team B, it is 13 but it is over the target 11. We will now use the 11 instead of the 13 because grade 13 exceeds target 11.

Now we need a percentage for Team B.    We add up the values for grade, we do this by saying, grade is 21, not 23.  Then we divide 21 by 31 (total target for Team B). This gives us 0.677%

Comment: Can you explain the calculation you try to make?

Comment: @ZoharPeled HI Zohar, I have provided an explanation and an example to help you understand the scenario and context. I hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I understand your calculation now.
You where close but for some reason you've used `count` instead of `sum`.
I came up with this query:

```
SELECT  [Team],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [Grade] > [Target] THEN [Target] ELSE [Grade] END) * 100 /
        SUM([Target]) As [Target]
FROM Grades
GROUP BY [Team]
```

That gave me this results for the sample data you've provided.

```
Team    Target
A       68
B       67
C       66
```

Comment: In my previous attempt I used count so I could calculate the average of grades (assuming target was always same). But you are right, for your real question this is the way to go.

Comment: @Zohar Peled  thank you very much!  Yeah, oddly enough I tried sum before but it was giving me wrong figures.  Now, it is producing correct figures.   (Very strange server)

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

By the light of the new information on the original question I will refine my answer like this:

```
select Team,cast(Sum(case when Grade>[Target] then [Target] else Grade end) as float)*100/SUM([Target]) from Grades
group by Team
```

I will keep the original answer below for further information.

> This will do the job:
>
> ```
> select Team,Sum([Grade])*100/Count([Grade])/Max([Target]) from Grades
> group by Team
> ```
>
> Since the `Target` value for the team is always the same in each row
>   we can use `min`,`max` to get a single value for the calculation. Note
>   that this calculation makes an integer division and is like "rounding
>   down" the result.
>
> If you need decimal precision in your percentage you will need to cast
>   your grade and target values to float or decimal:
>
> ```
> select Team,cast(Sum([Grade]) as float)*100/Count([Grade])/Max([Target]) from Grades
> group by Team
> ```
>
> Finally if you need a final rounded value just use `Round` function on
>   the final calculated value like `round(cast(Sum(Grade) as
>   float)*100/Count(Grade)/Max([Target]),0)`

Comment: Hi TSungar, your answer is great but I think my dataset was a lacking in diversity so it skipped a step.   Unfortunately, my Target Value for each team is not always the same.   If it was, somehow, your SQL query would have been perfect to my question.  (I edited my original post to help explain this further)

Comment: like this maybe: select Team,cast(Sum(case when Grade>[Target] then [Target] else Grade end) as float)*100/SUM([Target]) from Grades
group by Team

Comment: I will still save your answer as it definitely has helped in my limited knowledge so I appreciate your answer and effort into this.